# Division in Haskell on `Num` instances

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, division

Consider the following excerpt from GHCI:

```
Prelude> :t sum [1,2,3]
sum [1,2,3] :: Num a => a
Prelude> :t fromIntegral (length [1,2,3])
fromIntegral (length [1,2,3]) :: Num b => b
Prelude> :t sum [1,2,3] / fromIntegral (length [1,2,3])
sum [1,2,3] / fromIntegral (length [1,2,3]) :: Fractional a => a
```

I understand that both `sum [1,2,3]` and `fromIntegral (length [1,2,3])` are instances of `Num`. What puzzles me is, why does the compiler convert the operands to `Fractional`? I thought that numeric conversions had to be explicit in Haskell.

Thanks!

Comment: `Fractional` is also a `Num`.

Comment: Yes, I know that `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num`, but not every instance of `Num` can be converted to `Fractional`. So why is it converted in that case?

Comment: I don't believe `Num` defines `/` operator. `Fractional` does. So the only way your expression type checks is if your operands are `Fractional` instances. ghci is trying to pick the most general type it can. `Num` doesn't work in this case. It's not that `Num` is being converted to `Fractional`

Comment: Does it mean that the command `:t sum [1,2,3]` should return `Fractional a => a` instead of `Num a => a`?

Comment: Like I said in edited comment, the compiler is inferring the most general type it can for any given expression. For your given `sum` example that's `Num` but for the given division `/` example that's Fractional.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! Now I see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought that numeric conversions had to be explicit in Haskell.

That is correct, but here we have *numerical literals*. If you write `2`, that is *not* per se an `Int`, or an `Integer`. We do not know it at that point.

If we then for instance write `2 / 3`, then Haskell will derive that we use a function `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, so it concludes that `2` and `3` should be `Fractional`, so in this case it will use a floating point parser to parse the `2` literal.

In case you would however explicitly state that `2` is an `Int`, then it will go wrong:

```
Prelude> (2 :: Int) / 3

<interactive>:4:1: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
    • In the expression: (2 :: Int) / 3
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (2 :: Int) / 3
```

So by forcing Haskell to use an `Int`, Haskell sees no way to parse it as a type that supports the `(/)` function.

Now to make it more specific to your question, if we analyze `sum [1,2,3]`. `sum` has type `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`, so in case the elements of the list are `Fractional`, then the `sum ...` has also a `Fractional` type.

For the denominator you actually make an *explicit* conversion. Indeed, you write `fromIntegral (length [1,2,3])`. Now `length :: [a] -> Int` returns an `Int`. The `fromIntegral` will convert any `Integral` type to a generic `Num` type. So it can convert an `Int` to a `Float`.

Comment: Thanks! What I was missing was indeed the fact that the type of a numerical literal depends on the context in which it is used.